# Pubnub is sending heart beat to multiple uuid?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, pubnub

When I change uuid using

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
          console.log(window,'A')
          pubnub.destroy()
          pubnub.removeAllListeners()
          pubnub.removeAllListeners()
          pubnub.setUUID(myId);
          console.log(pubnub, 'Pubnub');
      }, [myId]);
```

It changes the uuid but still keep calling previous uuid?

Answer (score 0):

guess your pubnub methods are asynchronous, so you will se changes next render.

Comment: Your answer seems to be a "guess". This would be better as a comment/suggestion than an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

### To Destroy, or Not Destroy

It would seem that if you do `pubnub.destroy`, then `pubnub.[anything]` is not going to work (haven't actually tested it though).

There should be no need to do the `destroy`, but if you do really want to stop the heartbeats, stop receiving messages/events and destroy the `pubnub` object, try this:

```js
// this should stop the heartbeats because it stops the subscribe call
pubnub.unsubscribeAll();

// this just stops removes the message/event listeners that 
// receive published messages, presence events, status event, etc.
pubnub.removeAllListeners();

// this destroys the pubnub object for the GC to handle
pubnub.destroy();
```

#### Typescript

If using Typescript, methods `destroy` and `removeAllListeners` are not declared as available types so you can just do the following:

```js
// this should stop the heartbeats because it stops the subscribe call
pubnub.unsubscribeAll();

// this destroys the pubnub object for the GC to handle
pubnub.stop();
```

#### Changing the UUID

If you're changing the UUID, you need to instantiate a new PubNub object and set it in the config.

Here's code that will work to change the UUID but you probably just want to unsubscribe from all channels first then change the UUID and then subscribe to new channels.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(window,'A')
  pubnub.unsubscribeAll();
  pubnub.setUUID(newUUID);
  console.log(pubnub, 'Pubnub');
}, [newUUID]);
```

> Please comment on this answer to let me know why you need to change the UUID as this is not typical for most use cases?